# Fetching data from an API then sending it to an EJS file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send a json objectfetched with the fetch-api to an EJS file which loads when someone vists the website. The issue is I'm getting that the object sent is undefined by the time the page loads since it takes some time for the data to be fetched.

I could wrap the res.render with async and await to wait for the data to be fetched then render the page but this would slow down the website loading time. I want there to be a default value in the ejs file until the one from the api is fetched.

```
//One of the routes
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
fetchData(object => {
res.render("landingPage", { obj: object });
})

});

function fetchData(callback){
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/teachers") //Could change this to a find request to the data base directly like Teacher.find()...
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      return callback(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
```

```html
<!--In the HTML file-->
<h5><%= obj.someValue %></h5>
```

In the code I provided the server waits for the data to be fetched then renders the page. I want the page to load and when the fetching is done it adds the fetched object to the page. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code I provided the server waits for the data to be fetched then renders the page. I want the page to load and when the fetching is done it adds the fetched object to the page. How could I do that?

You can't, per se.

Your current implementation is akin to:

1. Calling someone
2. Asking them for information
3. Being put on hold
4. Them coming back and giving you the information

What you want would involve hanging up after step 2 so when they get back with the information, you're no longer there.

---

The closest you could come would be the return a document which includes some client-side JS which makes a second HTTP request for the data, and then modifies the DOM of the live page when it gets it.

This is generally known as Ajax. You can use `fetch` natively in modern browsers.

Comment: I've always heard about ajax but was intimidated to go near it. Now reading a bit more I can see how it could fix my problem. Hopefully it is not that much of a pain to  learn it haha. Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  const obj = await fetchData()
  res.render("landingPage", { obj });
});

function fetchData(){
  return fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/teachers")
      .then(res => res.json())
}
```

Comment: That's (arguably) nicer syntax for doing what the OP is already doing … but it doesn't do what they are asking for.